# Clam scan files on 14.04

Tags: clamav, clamtk

After running clam it found four files called win.trojan.Xored-1

What are they? They were in Chrome cache.

Comment: They must be trojans, downloaded from sites. But I do not think they can affect Ubuntu.

Comment: @Pilot6 http://www.scmagazine.com/malware-targets-linux-and-arm-architecture/article/391497/ O_O

Comment: This is very unlikely. I have a friend who offers a money bonus for someone who sends a WORKING virus for linux that does not need a long manual to install )))

Comment: @Zacharee1 Mother of god...

Comment: @Pilot6 There are quite a few articles on it. Search the ID OP provided.

Comment: I am not interested. I do not use Windows.

Comment: @Pilot6 it's targeted at Linux specifically. It also says, however, that it relies on the user having default logins for their devices, so it isn't like the king virus or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.scmagazine.com/malware-targets-linux-and-arm-architecture/article/391497/), They are files from a rather dangerous Trojan virus and rootkit.

The Trojan, called XOR.DDoS installs itself onto compatible Linux systems and hides its files so the user doesn't know it's there. It uses your computer to run DDoS attacks.

However, it relies on you having not changed any default logins on your devices, which means if you have a password you're probably OK. I would delete those files and maybe look into removing rootkits just in case, however.

The Avast blog has a more detailed article on it: https://blog.avast.com/2015/01/06/linux-ddos-trojan-hiding-itself-with-an-embedded-rootkit/

Comment: Oddly I have never used any default logins - system has always been password protected.  Thanks for the article - will check it out. I just deleted all odd files clam found including some html.exploit.CVE files and scanned again.

Comment: @danielp I still recommend checking for rootkits: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/chkrootkit/

Comment: I got this: Searching for Suckit rootkit...    Warning: /sbin/init INFECTED

Comment: Does this application allow you to remove rootkits?

Comment: I ran chkrootkit so no I don't think it does - or at least I don't know how to remove

Comment: Second answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/517/best-rootkit-removal-tool-for-a-server

Comment: Re-installed Ubuntu - after running chkrootkit suckit rootkit still appears - seems its a bug? Also ran clam and found some trojan agent html files it didn't like.

Comment: No, it isn't a bug, unless you did a full format (overwrite data with 0s). Rootkits have a tendency to persist over even quick formats. If you didn't even do a quick format, then it's definitely still there.

Comment: I reinstalled OS ie a new install from disk.

Comment: Just installing over the old installation?

Comment: A new installation from Wubi disk. I didn't do anything else - just installation. I thought that overwrites files? I just ran RKhunter and it didn't pick up suckit (although it did pick up postfix - which I seems to have installed itself). Can of worms - check, can opener - check.....

Comment: Reinstalling on top of the current installation merely replaces system files, and not even very well. The best thing to do is a secure erase of the drive and reinstall.

Comment: As it turns out its a false positive - well documented bug in chkrootkit

Comment: @danielp That's a relief